# wp_customize and selecting layout

Tags: php, wordpress, customization

So I'm trying to build a conditional statement to display different layouts depending on the option selected.

Having a bit of trouble.

```
$wp_customize->add_setting('layout', array(
  'default'           => 'stream',
  )); // add our default setting.
$wp_customize->add_control('layout', array(
  'label'      => __('Select layout', 'Ari'),
  'section'    => 'layout',
  'settings'   => 'layout',
  'type'       => 'radio',
  'choices'    => array(
    'stream'   => 'Stream',
    'grid'  => 'Grid',
  ),
)); // use radio buttons with (so far) two choices.
$wp_customize->add_section('layout' , array(
    'title' => __('Layout','Ari'),
)); // add our layout section in the customize panel.
```

Displaying our layout.

```
    <?php if ( get_theme_mod( 'stream' ) ) : ?>
    <p>stream</p> if ( have_posts() ) etc 
    <?php elseif ( get_theme_mod( 'grid' ) ) : ?>
    <p>grid</p> // if ( have_posts() )  etc
    <?php else : //Nothing ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Just...nothing. I've trawled through the codex and I can't see what I'm doing wrong. It just doesn't show any output.

@Stewartside points out that that I should use get_setting, I can't get this working though. Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

`get_theme_mod()` returns a string, not a boolean. Therefore, your `if` statements will always fail as they are expecting either `1` or `true` or `0` or `false`.

You should look into using `get_setting` within the `$wp_customize` functionality.

[Documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Customize_Manager/get_setting)

Comment: I've had a dig through and I can't work out how to do it. Am I going about this the correct way (in theory)? ie. output different php/html from a selected theme setting?

Comment: In theory yes, it is the correct way of doing it with if statements. The only problem is get_theme_mod retrieves a string when really you want a true or false.